# How to wire an Air Conditioner from the disconnect when exposed to physical damage?

Tags: electrical, wiring, air-conditioning

Is there a general recommended wiring method for connecting an air conditioner (condenser on exterior of home) to its disconnect that is both not subject to physical damage and able to withstand a lot of vibration?

Per [this question and answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/110947/36011), the LFNC whips that I see used on air conditioners installed at ground level without any surrounding protection everywhere can be interpreted as non-code compliant. Also, all flexible conduit options are subject to physical damage (refer to the code sections cited in ["Question #3" from this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/104859/36011)).

Therefore, I was planning to use 3/4" EMT with liquid-tight connectors from the disconnect to the AC. However, I am now thinking about rigid materials mating with the vibrating motor of the air conditioner also being a bad idea since it will likely shake the conduit/disconnect mounts loose from the mortar of my exterior wall over time. If not another wiring method: Is there potentially something I could use to make the mounts for the EMT and disconnect less-susceptible to failure from vibration?

Comment: When you say Air Conditioner you really mean the condenser or the air handler ?

Comment: I would not consider any method which is not flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean AC Condenser Unit : You can run EMT to the unit - typically a flex conduit cable is used (almost all installations I have seen use a flex conduit) but you can use emt if you like.

From your [LINK](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110947/is-it-okay-to-use-an-lfnc-whip-to-connect-air-conditioner-where-subject-to-physi)   **356.10 Uses Permitted**:

> Where flexibility is required for installation, operation, or
>   maintenance.

Use the Flexible Conduit to attach your condenser, connect your motor - use a strain relief on the physical wires and wire ties as well to limit the vibration of the wires.

Comment: I ended up just going with LFNC like everybody else and my inspector was okay with it.